# How to get value from href and assert with store value

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Following page source:

```
<td class="header">Email:</td>
<td align="left">
<a href="mailto:affweb6340@mailinator.com">affweb6340@mailinator.com</a>
</td>
```

I had store value in String em.

Assume Value store in em is affweb@some.com

What I'm trying to do is that I want to compare both value that is to be similar (Pass) if not (Fail).

I tried with XPath but did not get it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please add the code you've worked upon so far, in your question.

Comment: try to use regex. like href="?(.*?)"

Comment: Is that <a> the only anchor tag on your page? If it is, then there is a quick an easy solution. But if it isn't we need more of your page source in order to select the right web element.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following XPath locator to get the inner text of the anchor:

```
//td[text()='Email:']/following-sibling::a[1]/text()[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you have on that page, you can also use CssSelector
E.g.:

a) Partial matching for email links
`driver.findElement(By.CssSelector("a[href^='mailto:']")).getText()` // should return string affweb6340@mailinator.com

b) If you know have more, you can get a list and iterate over it to compare each email address (more time consuming)